# Failed to Start kony application

Tags: temenos-quantum

I just installed Kony Studio . I am trying to run the HelloWorld app on the Android emulator, always gives me this error:

```
Failure
rm failed for /sdcard/profiler_com.kony.HelloWorld.txt, Read-only file system
Installing kony application
353 KB/s (3438511 bytes in 9.504s) pkg: /data/local/tmp/luavmandroid.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
rm failed for -f, Read-only file system
Starting kony application
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.kony.HelloWorld/.Hello
World }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.kony.HelloWorld/com.kony.HelloWorld.HelloWorld} does
not exist
```

I have tried creating a new project, but didn't work.

Comment: Give some value to SD card memory in emulator in AVD and try once

Answer (score 2):

It is because `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`, You should set the minimum Android SDK API lower that your device in the project properties > Native > Android > SDK versions > Minimum

Answer (score 2):

Just put SDK versions of android in project properties. Min android version : 2.3 and max android version : 4.4. Also while creating avd add sd card memory as 216MB.

Answer (score 1):

When installing the Android SDK, you must install the correct versions exactly how is specifies in the installation guide found here:

http://docs.kony.com/6_5_PDFs/studio/kony_studio_installation_guide.pdf

Select the following components from the list of available packages:

- i. Android SDK Tools
- ii. Android SDK Platform-tools
- iii. Android 2.1
  (API 7).

Note: For Kony Studio 5.0 and below versions, you must necessarily install the
minimum supported SDK Platform Android 2.1, which inclues the Google APIs by
Google Inc., Android API 7, before you install any higher version SDK and Google
API.

- iv. Any version of Android SDK - above 2.1. (Preferably the latest SDK. Example. Android
  4.1 (API 16)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend support to older version android OS, you need to set the

> Project Settings -> Native Tab -> Android -> SDK versions -> Minimum: to lower version

[image: Screenshot] attached.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you're trying to install an app that has a higher minSdkVersion specified in its manifest than the device's API level.

Please change "Minimum SDK version" in your application settings to lower version that your device OS version.

You can do this by navigating project properties -> Native -> Android. Change here.

Minimum SDK version when you create a project is defaulted to 2.3 in Kony 6+. I wonder which device is that :)